# How do I freely move a div element within another div in my code?

Tags: html, css

So for my web page, I'm trying to position a div (the Start button) inside another existing parent div (The "Course-Block" in this case). What I'm trying to achieve is the white "Start" button you can see from the imgur link here. I know I'm not supposed to be posting images, however the schematic is of absolute relevance and necessity for this question.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5UTX.jpg

I've tried setting the "start-button" DIV to have absolute position (as you can see from my attempt on the code). However, any attempts to offset the div element inside the "container" DIV just makes it disappear.

HTML:

```
    <div class="Courses">
      <h1>Courses</h1>
      <div id="Year-7" class="Course-Block">
        <div class="Container Green">
          <span>Testing</span>
        </div>

        <div class="Start-Button">
          awdawd
        </div>

        <div class="Block-Content">
          <span>Example Paragraph</span>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div id="Year-8" class="Course-Block">
        <div class="Container Yellow">
          <span>Testinag</span>
        </div>

        <div class="Block-Content">
          <span>Example Paragraph</span>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div id="Year-9" class="Course-Block">
        <div class="Container Red">
          <span>testing</span>
        </div>

        <div class="Block-Content">
          <span>Example Paragraph</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
        .Course-Block{
          display: inline-block;
          margin: 0px 50px;
          border: 1px solid black;
          height: 400px;
          width: 300px;
        }

        .Courses{
          text-align: center;
          background-color: lightYellow
        }

        .Block-Content {
          border: 1px black solid;
          height: 350px;
          background-color: lightBlue;
          line-height: 350px;
          text-align: center;
        }

        .Container {
          height: 50px;
          font-size: 20px;
          font-family: Arial;
          background-color: white;
          line-height: 50px;
          text-align: center;
        }

        .Start-Button {
          position: absolute;
          background-color: Green;
          border: 1px solid black;
          z-index: 10;
        }

        span {
          display: inline-block;
          vertical-align: middle;
          line-height: normal;
        }
```

Full Website Code: https://jsfiddle.net/bwpxky7f/
I would recommend reading off from the link since it is much more clearer and it isn't much more then the code I have pasted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `position:relative` to `.course-block` and set the `.start-button` to be positioned to the bottom like so:

```
.Start-Button {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: Green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  z-index: 10;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
} 

.Course-Block{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution!, but can you also explain the code to me? I don't really get it. Why does the Course-block need to have a relative position, what does it actually do in this code?

Comment: I'd also like to ask on how I can adjust the element upwards/downwards. Is there a way?

Comment: An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor. If an absolute positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling. If you want to move the start-button up and down you can change the bottom and top values for example, bottom:10px;

Comment: This page should help https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Also, if the answer i provided works please accept as it as the answer :)